# Heroku Platform API - userinfo not supported. [RFC3986]

Tags: rest, curl, heroku

I'm getting this error message when trying to deploy from my GitHub private repo.

Setup App

Request

```
curl -n -X POST https://api.heroku.com/app-setups \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Accept:application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" \
-d '{
    "source_blob": {
        "url": "https://GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/USERNAME/REPO_NAME/zipball/master"
    }
}'
```

Response

```
{
    "id": "fc79eeab-28eb-4a83-99a2-53629057a3cf",
    "failure_message": null,
    "status": "pending",
    "app": {
        "id": "dd702dcd-7923-4742-85e4-58026f0b0a87",
        "name": "glacial-tor-54074"
    },
    "build": null,
    "manifest_errors": [],
    "postdeploy": null,
    "resolved_success_url": null,
    "created_at": "2020-06-30T05:42:55+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-30T05:42:55+00:00"
}
```

Build Status

Request

```
curl -n https://api.heroku.com/app-setups/fc79eeab-28eb-4a83-99a2-53629057a3cf \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Accept:application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

Response

```
{
    "id": "fc79eeab-28eb-4a83-99a2-53629057a3cf",
    "failure_message": "userinfo not supported.  [RFC3986]",
    "status": "failed",
    "app": {
        "id": "dd702dcd-7923-4742-85e4-58026f0b0a87",
        "name": "glacial-tor-54074"
    },
    "build": null,
    "manifest_errors": [],
    "postdeploy": null,
    "resolved_success_url": null,
    "created_at": "2020-06-30T05:42:55+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-30T05:42:56+00:00"
}
```